# Render Razor Partial View in Razor Component (Blazor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I am newly discovering Blazor and have been playing with some test projects to better gauge how I might include this in future projects. Coming from an MVC background I have started with an MVC project and added Razor components to it which I am nesting inside of my standard MVC razor pages.

Is the reverse possible? Can I do something equivalent to @Html.RenderPartial() inside of a Razor(Blazor) component?

For example

MVC View uses `@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Test>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))` to render a component

The component manages state etc and uses an equivilent of `@Html.RenderPartial("Someview.cshtml", someModel)` to render standard razor view with model binding.

Comment: You can share components with a [Razor Class Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: You can also use [RenderFragment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.renderfragment?view=aspnetcore-3.1) with content coming from a static html file or MVC View. Is that you're looking for ?

Comment: The fragment sounds like what I want, can you provide an example?

Comment: A quick and dirty way can be an iframe

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63229397/net-core-blazor-render-cshtml-partial-view-component-dynamically, you need to convert .cshtml into .razor (not too difficult for a partial view) and then you can either load it like my example or just with a normal tag `<Tag Attrib="value">`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [RenderFragment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.renderfragment?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to load an Html code from a static file, razor page or MVC view by loading its content from its URL.

**sample**

```cs
@page "/"
@page "/home"
@inject HttpClient _httpClient

<h1>Welcome</h1>
@_renderFragment

@code {
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            using var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:4321/WelcomFragment").ConfigureAwait(false);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            _renderFragment = builder =>
            {
                builder.OpenElement(1, "p");
                builder.AddContent(2, new MarkupString(content));
                builder.CloseElement();
            };
            base.OnInitialized();
        }
}
```

Comment: @Neo, if you need authentication you inject an `HttpClient` with a `AuthorizationMessageHandler` or a `IHttpClientFactory` providing an `HttpClient` with `AuthorizationMessageHandler` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attach-tokens-to-outgoing-requests

Comment: Looks fine to me, more here: https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/