# .net core Blazor render cshtml partial view component dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my blazor `.razor` component I have this code...

```cs
... stuff ...

@HistoricDeck

... stuff ...

@code
{
    protected GameDataModel GameData { get; set; }

    protected RenderFragment HistoricDeck { get; set; }

    protected async Task LoadDeck(FriendSupportModel deck, DeckType type)
    {
        HistoricDeck = builder =>
        {
            var deckFragment = new SupportDeck() {
                GameData = GameData,
                AssetList = GameData.AssetList,
                Deck = deck.normalDeck,
                Type = DeckType.Standalone,
            };
            builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
            builder.AddAttribute(1, "SupportDeck", deckFragment);
            builder.CloseElement();
        };
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

LoadDeck is called by an `@onclick=` event on the page, I wish to dynamically render a new SupportDeck() into the page. How do I do this? The code below is non-functional (breakpoints in SupportDeck.cshtml are not hit, for example).

SupportDeck.cshtml.cs:

```cs
public class SupportDeck
{
    public FriendServantListModel Deck { get; set; }
    public DeckType Type { get; set; }
    public GameDataModel GameData { get; set; }
    public AssetList AssetList { get; set; }
}
```

SupportDeck.cshtml:

```
@model Project.Views.Shared.SupportDeck
... stuff ...
@if (Model.Deck != null) {
<p>Hello world</p>
}
... stuff ...
```

Here is how I would normally render this view fragment in a non-blazor page:

```cs
@{
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("SupportDeck", new SupportDeck
    {
        Deck = Model.FriendSupport.normalDeck,
        Type = DeckType.Normal,
        GameData = Model.GameData,
        AssetList = Model.AssetList
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved by turning the `.cshtml` into a `.razor` template, then this:

```cs
        HistoricDeck = builder =>
        {
            builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(SupportDeckItem));
            builder.AddMultipleAttributes(1, new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                {"Deck", deck},
                {"Type", deckType},
                {"GameDataItem", gameData},
                {"AssetList", gameData.AssetList}
            });
            builder.CloseComponent();
        };
        StateHasChanged();
```