# How to render Partial Views in Blazor using Razor pages

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side, syncfusion

I am trying to figure out how to use Partial Views from a Razor page in a Blazor Server app using .Net 7.
I have a grid (using syncfusion) and have created a custom button.

[image]

I am using the OnCommandClicked event handler to call my OnCommandClicked function which will pass SiteModel object a partial view.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28YZo.png)

However
I have tried a few things and I cannot get the partial view to show...
Any help would be great!

So far I have referred to the following docs; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-7.0

I am expecting to click the button and to then navigate to the partial view to display only records linked to the row data.

Comment: Did you read [Why can't I use partial view in a razor (blazor) component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70560993)

Comment: Use razor components and pass parameters between them will be the best idea

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi using Razor components is a great choice..

Answer (score 1):

To fulfill your requirement, you can utilize the Uri helper for routing. This involves passing the context data from the button click event to the URL specified in the "Link" variable of the DataGrid data. This action will route the page to the corresponding URL. Following this, you should create a new Razor page for routing. Define the routing URL and specify the parameters to be received. Initialize it with the necessary details.

For more information, you can refer to the following documentation: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/datagrid/column-template#using-hyperlink-column-and-performing-routing-on-click